# SVG support in jsdom and google charts

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to generate some google charts server side in node.js.

```
jsdom.env({
    html: '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div style="width: 900px; height: 500px;" id="googlechart"></div></body></html>',
    scripts: ['https://www.google.com/jsapi'],
    done: function (err, window) {
        (some stuff)
    }
})
```

The reason is a bug in webkit or in wkhtmltopdf with inline SVG. If the SVG is a object pointing to a .xhtml file the pdf is ok, otherwise random errors in the rendering.

The google.load() dynamic loading doesn't seems to work, but loading locally the otherwise dynamically loaded js files from google seems to be ok. The google.visualization seems to be operative.
However after the chart.draw(..) in the document I can find only a superultrageneric:

"Graphics is not supported"

error in a div and no actual svg in sight.
I've executed Modrnizer inside the jsdom page just for fun and the SVG and Inline SVG test are on "false". But since I've find lot of people who says to have successful generated server side svg with jsdom I suppose this is not that meaningful.
Anyone have tried something similar and have some suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom

Comment: It would help those who would like to help you to actually be able to see the reports of those who say they've been successful generating server-side SVG with jsdom. (Can you provide links to them?)

Comment: this one seems successuful, but obviously with another library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362680/server-side-highstock-charts-generation-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I am also still seeing this issue in 2016 with jsdom 8.4.0 latest version.

I have an issue logged on their GitHub that explains I either see error
var data = new window.google.visualization.DataTable();
                       ^
TypeError: window.google.visualization.DataTable is not a function

or
the google.load never returns properly otherwise..if I dont use the autoload in script.
https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1463

Trying to load it sync all in script tag using googles autoload way gives this error:
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a function

If I change it to use the google.load after jsdom gives done event it just exists and I get no details

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
console.log("Google onload callback called");
window.docharting();
});
```

full code:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

//TODO newscript way to load, can update someday
//http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js
//google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
//google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(docharting);
jsdom.env({
html: '

',
scripts: ["http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"],
FetchExternalResources :["script", "link", "img"],
ProcessExternalResources: ["script"],
done: function (err, window) {
if(err){
console.log("err: " + err);
return;
}else{
console.log("Initiating charting...");
    var google = window.google;
    console.log("Google visualization: " + google.visualization);
    window.docharting = function(err, obj){
        console.log("err " + JSON.stringify(err) + ", obj: " + obj);
        console.log("Starting chart drawing...");
                // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        d = window.document;
        elm = d.getElementById('map');

        console.log("Got map container " + el + ", starting chart rendering...");

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(elm);

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            console.log("Chart ready, capturing image uri");
          imageURI = chart.getImageURI();
          console.log(imageURI);
        });

        console.log("Data ready, starting drawing...");
        chart.draw(data, options);
        console.log("Done drawing");
    }

    if(google){

        //google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        //google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        //  console.log("Google onload callback called");
        //  window.docharting();
        //});
        window.docharting();
    }else{
        console.log("Google apis did not initialize properly");
    }
}
}
});
```